# Signing NSIS Uninstaller from Linux or Mac

Tags: nsis

I am porting our NSI installer to Linux and Mac instead of Windows to better integrate with our Maven build system.

We need to sign our installer and uninstaller. This was done as suggested at http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Signing_an_Uninstaller, but I just realized that it tries to run the tempinstaller to force it to produce the uninstaller.exe which can then be signed.

Obviously this trick doesn't work too well on *Nix systems and make this part of the process non-portable.

Does anyone has a better solution. I'm no expert at NSIS and wondering if there is a clever way to get the uninstall.exe so that it can be signed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a real solution to this.

The installer and uninstaller uses the same exe code and only checks a flag (`FH_FLAGS_UNINSTALL` in `firstheader`) on startup to see if it is a uninstaller. Just flipping this bit is not enough though, the program would fail the CRC check and even if you bypass that the uninstaller data is compressed so you would have to decompress that to the correct location in the file. To actually accomplish this you would have to write a custom tool. You can see this operation in the NSIS source in exec.c if you search for `EW_WRITEUNINSTALLER`.

Comment: What's the difference between writing an uninstaller and just copying an uninstaller behavior (but into the "install' section) into a brand new installer and bundling that along?

Comment: Answering my own question.... the trickiest part appears to be the self-delete behavior of the uninstaller (copies to TEMP and then deletes itself on reboot).    The [SelfDel](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/SelfDel_plug-in) plug-in has a trick for handling this, but there's a warning at the bottom stating Kaspersky has labeled the technique as a threat due to the memory injection/explorer suspend technique that it uses.  As an alternative, there are published NSIS `!ifdef INNER` techniques for self-execution which are probably viable albeit reinventing the proverbial wheel.

Answer (score 0):

> We need to sign our installer and uninstaller. This was done as suggested at http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Signing_an_Uninstaller, but I just realized that it tries to run the tempinstaller to force it to produce the uninstaller.exe which can then be signed. [...] this trick doesn't work too well on *Nix systems and make this part of the process non-portable.

If you exploit a stub installer for uninstall operations (no payload), this appears to be possible.

It will spawn an `uninstall.exe` process from the `$TEMP` folder, which is then capable of deleting `$INSTDIR`.

This script will create a stub (un)installer which can then be Authenticode Signed.  It will compile on Windows, MacOS and Linux.

[image: install masqueraded screenshot]

#### Caveats:

- You'll have to manually bundle this into the installer (trivial)
- You'll have to manage your own uninstall registry entries (trivial)
- The look and feel may not match NSIS's default for uninstallers
- You'll see the installer open twice (first from `$INSTDIR`, second from `$TEMP`).  This is a child process which allows `uninstall.exe` to delete itself, similar to how [NSIS does it in the `Section "Uninstall"`](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/AppendixD.html#errorlevels).
- You'll need a secondary `.nsi` script dedicated to uninstall operations, cumbersome if you have a lot of shared logic between your install/uninstall sections.

  - Worse, you'll have to **AVOID the `"Uninstall"` section title**, as you'll be placed into the same problem as the OP when that bytecode is generated.
- When explicitly running from `$TEMP` some relative file logic will be incorrect.  The example passes these back in as a `$DELETE_DIR`, `$DELETE_EXE` respectively.

#### The code:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!include x64.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh

!define MUI_PRODUCT "My App"
!define MUI_VERSION "1.0.0"

; Masquerade the title
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Uninstall My App"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Remove My App from your computer"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_TEXT "Uninstallation Complete"
!define MUI_INSTFILESPAGE_FINISHHEADER_SUBTEXT "Uninstall was completed successfully."

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro GetParameters

RequestExecutionLevel admin
CRCCheck On

OutFile "uninstall.exe"
Name "Uninstall"

Var /GLOBAL RESPAWN
Var /GLOBAL DELETE_DIR
Var /GLOBAL DELETE_EXE

Section
  ; Masquerade as uninstall
  SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:Uninstall"

  ${GetParameters} $0
  ${GetOptions} "$0" "/RESPAWN=" $RESPAWN
  ${GetOptions} "$0" "/DELETE_DIR=" $DELETE_DIR
  ${GetOptions} "$0" "/DELETE_EXE=" $DELETE_EXE

  ${If} $RESPAWN != ""
    ; We're running from $TEMP; Perform the uninstall
    !define yay "We're running from $EXEPATH, yay, we can remove the install directory!$\n$\n"
    !define myvars "$\tRESPAWN$\t$RESPAWN$\n$\tDELETE_EXE$\t$DELETE_EXE$\n$\tDELETE_DIR$\t$DELETE_DIR"
    MessageBox MB_OK "${yay}${myvars}"
    ; Your uninstall code goes here
    ; RMDir /r $DELETE_DIR\*.*
    ; Delete "$DESKTOP\${MUI_PRODUCT}.lnk"
    ; Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\${MUI_PRODUCT}\*.*"
    ; RmDir  "$SMPROGRAMS\${MUI_PRODUCT}"
    ; Delete Uninstaller And Unistall Registry Entries
    ; DeleteRegKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\${MUI_PRODUCT}"
    ; DeleteRegKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${MUI_PRODUCT}"  

    ; Remove the old version of ourself
    ClearErrors
    Delete $DELETE_EXE
    IfErrors 0 +3
    MessageBox MB_OK "File could NOT be deleted: $DELETE_EXE"
    Goto +2
    MessageBox MB_OK "File was successfully deleted: $DELETE_EXE"

    ; Remove ourself from $TEMP after reboot
    Delete /REBOOTOK $EXEPATH

    ; ${If} ${RunningX64}
    ;   ${EnableX64FSRedirection}
    ; ${EndIf}
    SetDetailsPrint textonly
    DetailPrint "Completed"
  ${Else}
    ; We're NOT running from $TEMP, copy to temp and respawn ourself
    GetTempFileName $0
    CopyFiles "$EXEPATH" "$0"
    Exec '"$0" /RESPAWN=1 /DELETE_DIR="$EXEDIR" /DELETE_EXE="$EXEPATH"'
    Quit
  ${EndIf}
SectionEnd

Function .onInit
  ; ${If} ${RunningX64}
  ;   SetRegView 64
  ;   ${DisableX64FSRedirection}
  ; ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

In the process on the NSIS wiki page, running the installer is needed to extract the generated uninstaller.

But there are other Linux/macOS tools that can also extract the generated uninstaller from the installer exe, such as 7-Zip.